# Notice: Undefined index: id magento2

Tags: magento2

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined index: id in /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-config/Model/Config/Structure/Element/Iterator.php on line 63
```

Comment: From when you get this issue ?

Comment: From  Admin area.
Stores -> Configuration.

Comment: Can you please explain in detail, about the scenario ?

Comment: have you installed any custom module ?

Comment: I think that the problem  comes from this (iwd extension)  one checkout page.